# R: extract sets in arbitrary intersection from a data frame

Tags: r, set, dplyr, tidyverse, set-intersection

I have a three column data frame. I want to find which "samples" are TRUE for value in arbitrary sets across "group". I used UpSetR to draw intersection sets, but now I need to extract the actual values. In the examples, e.g., I might want to get the samples that are TRUE in group A but not in B or C. In the second, I want to get samples TRUE in group A and B but not C. I need to do this over a large number of samples and groups, where I can provide a group or groups, and extract samples TRUE just for that intersection set.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
#> Loading tidyverse: tibble
#> Loading tidyverse: tidyr
#> Loading tidyverse: readr
#> Loading tidyverse: purrr
#> Loading tidyverse: dplyr
#> Conflicts with tidy packages ----------------------------------------------
#> filter(): dplyr, stats
#> lag():    dplyr, stats

# Here's what I have
have <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~sample, ~value,
      "a",     "x",  TRUE,
      "a",     "y",  TRUE,
      "a",     "z",  TRUE,
      "b",     "x", FALSE,
      "b",     "y",  TRUE,
      "b",     "z", FALSE,
      "c",     "x", FALSE,
      "c",     "y", FALSE,
      "c",     "z",  TRUE
  )

have
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   group sample value
#>   <chr>  <chr> <lgl>
#> 1     a      x  TRUE
#> 2     a      y  TRUE
#> 3     a      z  TRUE
#> 4     b      x FALSE
#> 5     b      y  TRUE
#> 6     b      z FALSE
#> 7     c      x FALSE
#> 8     c      y FALSE
#> 9     c      z  TRUE

# Get samples where value is true only in group a
have %>%
  spread(group, value) %>%
  filter(a & !b & !c) %>%
  pull(sample) %>%
  unique()
#> [1] "x"

# Get samples where value is true in A and B but not C
have %>%
  spread(group, value) %>%
  filter(a & b & !c) %>%
  pull(sample) %>%
  unique()
#> [1] "y"
```

Comment: Your code works, so what is the problem?

Comment: It won't scale. If I have 100 groups, let's say, that's a lot of manual typing, and wouldn't be very modular.

Comment: I see, so you want all combinations of groups in your `filter`?

Comment: Yes. More interested in providing a single group for samples that are uniquely TRUE. Bonus if I can specify one or two or three, and have the rest be false.

Comment: I guess with appropriate use of rlang/tidyeval, you could wrap your own code in a function. I don't know the details of that stuff yet, though.

Comment: See my updates for a more general function to handle your case.

Answer (score 3):

You should retain your data in the spread format, I guess. From there, you can left join tuples of conditions:

```
DF = spread(have, group, value)

condDF = data.frame(
  id = 1:3, 
  a = TRUE, 
  b = c(FALSE, TRUE , TRUE), 
  c = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE) )

left_join(condDF, DF)

Joining, by = c("a", "b", "c")
  id    a     b     c sample
1  1 TRUE FALSE FALSE      x
2  2 TRUE  TRUE FALSE      y
3  3 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE   <NA>
```

I think it's cleanest to keep this in a table, but if you insist on vectors of samples...

```
left_join(condDF, DF) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(samples = list(setdiff(sample, NA)))

Joining, by = c("a", "b", "c")
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id   samples
  <int>    <list>
1     1 <chr [1]>
2     2 <chr [1]>
3     3 <chr [0]>
```

(I tried `nest` here but got overcomplicated output.)

---

For the OP's special case...

- Only passing one condition at a time
- Specifying only the groups that are TRUE (with the others implicitly FALSE)

we can use `replace`:

```
f = function(gs, dat = DF, all_gs = setdiff(names(dat), vn), vn = "sample"){
  base_cond = all_gs %>% setNames(rep(FALSE, length(.)), .) %>% 
    as.list %>% as.data.frame
  replace(base_cond, gs, TRUE) %>% left_join(DF) %>% pull(!! vn)
}
```

Usage

```
> f("a")
Joining, by = c("a", "b", "c")
[1] "x"
> f(c("a", "b"))
Joining, by = c("a", "b", "c")
[1] "y"
```

Or in data.table...

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(DF)

fdt = function(gs, dat = DT, all_gs = setdiff(names(dat), vn), vn = "sample"){
  base_cond = all_gs %>% setNames(rep(FALSE, length(.)), .) %>% as.list
  dat[replace(base_cond, gs, TRUE), on=all_gs, ..vn][[1]]
}

fdt("a")
# [1] "x"
fdt(c("a","b"))
# [1] "y"
```

Comment: Thanks Frank. This is helpful, but problem is I have many "groups" making it tedious and error-prone to type them all out in the condDF. I want to be able to provide a particular group or groups to find samples exclusive to that group where value is TRUE.

Comment: @StephenTurner I don't know what "provide" means if not "pass as input at some point"..? If you detail what sort of input format you expect to give in the OP, maybe there's a clean way to construct something like condDF from it. Is it you want to interactively pass `"a"` and then `c("a", "b")` for your examples?

Comment: I'll try to reformulate it with example code. Verbally: I want to give a function (pipe, filter statement, etc) a group by name, e.g., `a`, or `c("a", "b"), and return samples that are TRUE uniquely in a but FALSE in others, or TRUE in A and B and false in others.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I just need to go through it until I understand what it's doing.

Comment: @StephenTurner Cool. If you find a way to improve my (hacky) construction of base_cond, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: Hacky is fine if it works. Didn't know about base replace function. Now I need to grok tidyeval.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function with `dplyr` + `rlang`, which either returns the correct intersect filter when an inclusion group is provided, or returns all correct combinations of intersect filters when `all = TRUE`. Should work for any number of unique group levels:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(tidyr)

inter_sets = function(groups, all = FALSE){

  filter_sets = function(filter_expr){
    have %>%
      spread(group, value) %>%
      filter(!!parse_quosure(filter_expr)) %>%
      pull(sample) %>%
      unique()
  } 

  if(is_true(all)){  

  combins = unique(have$group) %>%
    c(paste0("!", .)) %>%
    combn(length(.)/2) %>%
    t() %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    filter(apply(., 1, function(x) length(unique(gsub("!", "", x))) == ncol(.) & !(length(grep("!", x)) %in% c(0, ncol(.))))) %>%
    unite("expressions", names(.), sep = " & ")

  combins$value = sapply(combins$expressions, filter_sets)

  return(combins)

  }else if(is_false(all)){

  combins = unique(have$group) %>%
    {c(.[match(groups, .)], paste0("!", .[-match(groups, .)]))} %>%
    paste(collapse = " & ")

  return(filter_sets(combins))  
  }  
}
```

**Result:**

```
> inter_sets("a")
[1] "x"

> inter_sets(c("a", "b"))
[1] "y"

> inter_sets(c("a", "c"))
[1] "z"

> inter_sets(all = TRUE)
  expressions value
1  a & b & !c     y
2  a & c & !b     z
3 a & !b & !c     x
4  b & c & !a      
5 b & !a & !c      
6 c & !a & !b
```

**Note:**

The idea for the "all combination method" is to find all grouping intersection combinations, and remove unnecessary combinations like `a & b & c` or `a & b & !a`; construct the expressions with `paste`, and apply the filter over all expressions by first parsing them into quosures via `parse_quosure` and returning the result as a vector.

Comment: @Stephen Turner Let me know if instead of listing all combinations, you would prefer to be able to supply the inclusion groups like in Frank's answer. That is easy to modify in my answer.

Comment: Nice, yeah that's what I meant with your inter_sets function. The OP would prefer to pass `a & b` or `c("a", "b")` instead of having to write the negation for `c`, though, I guess.

Comment: @Frank Updated my answer.